# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView

Tags: android

I'm having this log (of course with the crash of my activity) when trying to go Chat Activity. I am following the tutorial of smack xmpp chat application It happens only when i try to open chat activity : Any suggestion at what i can do to the line 2??? Greetings log :

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testproject.rooster/com.testproject.rooster.ChatActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.testproject.rooster.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.rooster-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.testproject.rooster.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:16) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 23 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">

    <co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView
        android:id="@+id/rooster_chat_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gradle file that has to imported . 
**build.gradle**

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation ('com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the library `com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui` is not included properly.

Make sure the line:

```
implementation 'com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.3'
```

is inside `dependencies {}` section.
Like in this file
https://github.com/blikoon/Rooster/blob/master/Rooster/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

> **Didn't find** class **`"co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView"`**

**First** make sure you have added :

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

In repositories of the `Build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**Second**, error says it couldn't find that class and in the documentation and the library, the package name [looks different](https://github.com/timigod/android-chat-ui/tree/master/chat-ui/src/main/java/co/intentservice/chatui) than what you've added in the xml codes.

So, replace the dependency with this :

```
implementation 'com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.4'
```

And then use this tag:

```
<co.intentservice.chatui.ChatView
```

Instead of:

```
<co.devcenter.androiduilibrary.ChatView
```